# order clause with varchar field containing numbers and text

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-order-by

the sql:

```
create table users(username varchar(256));

insert into users values ('1112');
insert into users values ('126');
insert into users values ('124');
insert into users values ('cats');

select * from users order by username;
```

results in the order: `1112, 124, 126, cats`

Is there a way to have the order clause be 'alphabetical, but numerical if a number', i.e: `124, 126, 1112,cats`

I tried:

`select * from users order by ('000'::varchar || username)`

but that doesn't help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select *
from users 
order by
  case
    when username ~ '^[0-9]+$' then username::bigint
    else null
  end,
  username;
```

for data:

```
insert into users values ('1112');
insert into users values ('126');
insert into users values ('124');
insert into users values ('22');
insert into users values ('cats');
```

gives:

```
"22"
"124"
"126"
"1112"
"cats"
```

Answer (score 1):

some ugly hack comes fast:

```
t=# select * from users 
order by ascii(username), regexp_replace(username,'[a-z]','0','g')::bigint, username;
                    username
------------------------------------------------
 124
 126
 1112
 cats
(4 rows)
```

with idea that

- ascii code of digits is ascending and before letters
- regexp_replace will sort numbers, not digits
- lastly alphabetical order